# OS and BIOS do not recognize memory correctly

Tags: windows, memory, bios

I'm having problem with my PC. For some reason my OS and BIOS do not recognize the memory correctly, although it used to recognize it. I have 12GB but only 8GB recognized. I have Rampage III motherboard, which supports up to 24GB.

I'm running it on Windows 7 Home Premium and I have 2GB × 6 sticks.

If I use CPU-Z to verify it, and it shows 12GB for the memory.

Any ideas?

Comment: What changed between when it worked and when it stopped working?

Comment: If the BIOS won't recognise the memory correctly then its a waste of your time worrying about what the OS can or can not see - it only knows what the BIOS tells it.

Comment: I didnt realize what changes I made. the CPU-Z recognize there's 12gb though

Comment: Since Rampage III supports triple channel memory and I'm assuming 3x4GB sticks, you may want to try putting the last stick into a different slot and see if that changes things.  Also, for the future, include your OS, the number of sticks of RAM, etc..

Comment: Are you sure you are using Home Premium and not Home Basic as the limit for Home Basic is 8GB of RAM (opposed to 16GB for Home Premium)?

Comment: It's not possible for CPU-Z to show 12GB if BIOS shows only 8GB.

Comment: Try to update the bios to its latest Firmware.

Comment: @AndrewM., [the question](http://superuser.com/revisions/411082/1) says 6x2GB, not 3x4GB. But you are on the right track with the channel testing.

Comment: @Synetech: Unfortunately, this information was missing when it was originally on SF. :(

Comment: @AndrewM., I don't think that's correct. According to the [timeline], the original question said 2x6GB and then it was migrated 1:23 later. I'm not too familiar with how dual-/triple-channel works, but if it is works such that one of a pair in a channel kills the whole channel, then your idea would be right. If it simply forces the motherboard to revert to single-channel, then there may be something else wrong with the board or RAM sticks.

Comment: @Synetech, I answered when this was on Serverfault before it was migrated here; the modification history does not carry over.

Comment: @Andrew, interesting. I wonder if ordinaryman can reply here. Obviously an account here is not automatically created, so I suppose they get a notification on SF that it was migrated.

Comment: Accounts are actually created on the StackExchange network--so an account on ServerFault can be used on every SX site (Serverfault, Superuser, Stack Overflow, etc.).  But I think this conversation probably doesn't belong on the comments section! :)

Answer (score 0):

I would try running either [Memtest86](http://www.memtest86.com/) or [Memtest86+](http://www.memtest.org/) (they are very similar - Memtest86+ was "forked" from Memtest86 a few years ago). Both are available to download for free. These programs perform comprehensive tests on RAM.

I would try just testing 1 stick at a time and to be really sure, I'd also test each slot separately. It might take a long time, but it's the only way you can be sure.